# Pip cannot install Dryscrape

Tags: python, qt, pip, lxml

I am trying to install dryscrape on my windows 10 labtop with pip and I have python 3.5.

I start off with...

```
C:\Users\Nick L>pip install dryscrape
Collecting dryscrape
Collecting webkit-server>=1.0 (from dryscrape)
  Using cached webkit-server-1.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): xvfbwrapper in c:\users\nick l\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from dryscrape)
Collecting lxml (from dryscrape)
  Using cached lxml-3.6.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: webkit-server, lxml
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for webkit-server ... error
  Complete output from command "c:\users\nick l\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\NICKL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-7a22xxh7\\webkit-server\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\NICKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj_ciouzupip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  'qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'src/webkit_server'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for webkit-server
  Running setup.py clean for webkit-server
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lxml ... error
  Complete output from command "c:\users\nick l\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\NICKL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-7a22xxh7\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\NICKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpei52rbaspip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  Building lxml version 3.6.0.
  Building without Cython.
  ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
  ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

  Using build configuration of libxslt
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron
  copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build webkit-server lxml
Installing collected packages: webkit-server, lxml, dryscrape
  Running setup.py install for webkit-server ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\users\nick l\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\NICKL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-7a22xxh7\\webkit-server\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\NICKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-qe2elwh1-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    'qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'src/webkit_server'

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\users\nick l\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\NICKL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-7a22xxh7\\webkit-server\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\NICKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-qe2elwh1-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\NICKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7a22xxh7\webkit-server\
```

I try to install lxml from there but get something similar...

```
C:\Users\Nick L>pip install lxml
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-3.6.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lxml ... error
  Complete output from command "c:\users\nick l\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\NICKL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-yzwahx9x\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\NICKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpv1xs5psnpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  Building lxml version 3.6.0.
  Building without Cython.
  ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
  ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

  Using build configuration of libxslt
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron
  copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
  copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\users\nick l\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\NICKL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-yzwahx9x\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\NICKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-p2l6zf7u-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Building lxml version 3.6.0.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\users\nick l\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\NICKL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-yzwahx9x\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\NICKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-p2l6zf7u-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\NICKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-yzwahx9x\lxml\
```

Then I proceed to install webkit-server and it also fails....

```
C:\Users\Nick L>pip install webkit-server
Collecting webkit-server
  Using cached webkit-server-1.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: webkit-server
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for webkit-server ... error
  Complete output from command "c:\users\nick l\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\NICKL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-582dkt3w\\webkit-server\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\NICKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpna6x8w4kpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  'qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'src/webkit_server'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for webkit-server
  Running setup.py clean for webkit-server
Failed to build webkit-server
Installing collected packages: webkit-server
  Running setup.py install for webkit-server ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\users\nick l\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\NICKL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-582dkt3w\\webkit-server\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\NICKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-5p_n5o5r-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    'qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'src/webkit_server'

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\users\nick l\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\NICKL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-582dkt3w\\webkit-server\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\NICKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-5p_n5o5r-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\NICKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-582dkt3w\webkit-server\
```

QT 5.7 is already installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: Ive also tried installing lxml manually with `pip install Downloads\lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win32.whl` but am getting the error `lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: I was able to successfully install lxml by installing a whole bunch of dependencies both on windows and linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that dryscrape does not support windows. Although, they mention you may be able to get it to work on cygwin. I am currently attempting to install under linux and failing to build wheel. See dryscrape docs.

I'd also like to add that you can use Anaconda on windows.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently finding difficulty in installing dryscrape on AWS Linux.
There were errors can't find src/web-server etc.
This github [answer](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape/issues/45) was all you need.
You just need to add this line in requirements.txt

```
-e git+https://github.com/niklasb/webkit-server.git#egg=webkit-server
```

Answer (score 1):

dryscrape isn't compatible with qt 5.6+. You need qt <= 5.5 due to qt WebKit/WebEngine requirement. For the record, I believe that qt4 is much more widely used still, so maybe go with qt 4.8.6. I've verified that 4.8.6 build works with dryscrape with no issues.

Source: [dryscrape](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape#user-content-a-word-about-qt-56)